# PHP and mysql error when moved from testing server to live server

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am experiencing a strange problem. I have a simply web from with some validation rules which I have been running on my pc for a few weeks which updates a database. It has all be running fine during the testing phase running on localhost

I have since moved the web form and database to my server and when entering data which should and is accepted on my local machine I get the following error

Error : You are attempting to enter information which cannot be stored or contains code. Please refesh the from and try again
Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'entryID' at row 1

Here is the basic code for the form processing

```
mysql_connect ("host", "username" , "password") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("name of database");

$query= "INSERT INTO entry (entryID, studentName , tutorName , procedureName , grade , studentReflection , tutorComments,  professionalism , communication , alert , dispute ) VALUES ('NULL', '".$options1."' , '".$options2." ' , '".$procedure."' , '".$grade."' , '".$studentReflection."', '".$tutorComments."' , '".$professionalism."' , '".$communication."' , '".$alert."' , '".$dispute."' )";


mysql_query($query) or die ('Error : You are attempting to enter information which cannot be stored or contains code. Please refesh the from and try again<br>' .mysql_error());


echo "<h3>The database has been updated.</br> Thank You </br><a href='form.php'>Enter another procedure</h3>"; 
}
?>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you post the code and the query people will have a chance to solve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing single quote around `NULL`.

I think you have auto-increment option set for `entryID`

```
$query= "INSERT INTO entry (entryID, studentName , tutorName , procedureName , grade , studentReflection , tutorComments,  professionalism , communication , alert , dispute ) VALUES (NULL, '".$options1."' , '".$options2." ' , '".$procedure."' , '".$grade."' , '".$studentReflection."', '".$tutorComments."' , '".$professionalism."' , '".$communication."' , '".$alert."' , '".$dispute."' )";
```

or try `''` instead of `NULL` itself

```
$query= "INSERT INTO entry (entryID, studentName , tutorName , procedureName , grade , studentReflection , tutorComments,  professionalism , communication , alert , dispute ) VALUES ('', '".$options1."' , '".$options2." ' , '".$procedure."' , '".$grade."' , '".$studentReflection."', '".$tutorComments."' , '".$professionalism."' , '".$communication."' , '".$alert."' , '".$dispute."' )";
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine entryID is an auto incrementing field? if so just remove it from the query.